# Wordpress Remove CPT Slug with hierarchical

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to remove the CPT slug with hierarchical urls:

www.test.com/cpt-slug/post-name/ > www.test.com/post-name

Which I have done fine and it is working with the below code however when I have a children post i.e www.test.com/post-name/child-post-name it doesn't seem to work. I will also need this to work for this type of url too www.test.com/post-name/child-post-name/another-child-post-name

```
      function rewrite_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
      if ( self::$post_type != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) return $permalink;

      // Get post
      if (!$post) return $permalink;

      return strtr($permalink,array('/' . self::$post_type . '/' => '/'));
  }
  public static function holiday_parse_request( $query ) {
    $counts = array( 2, 4 );
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || !in_array(count( $query->query ), $counts) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
          return;
      }
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', self::$post_type, 'page' ) );

      if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
          $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', self::$post_type, 'page' ) );
      }

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: Hi Chin,
It's the children pages for the parent i.e www.test.com/post-name/child-post-name << this url
thanks

Comment: I mean, is the url returning a 404, or is it not generating the url at all?

Comment: Ah sorry it redirects to the homepage but its coming up 404 in the redirection plugin

Comment: OK so i added an error log with $query->query['name'] and it doesn't seem to be setting anything not sure if that helps at all?